# How to measure the rendering time of a View?

Tags: java, android

I'm using a `ChartEngine` to create scatter plots. Each scatter plot is a `View`.
How would I measure the time required to render a `View`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

```
class MyView extends View {

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Time t = new Time();
        t.setToNow();
        long timeStart = t.toMillis(false);

        super.onDraw(canvas);

        t.setToNow();
        long timeToDraw = t.toMillis(false) - timeStart;

    }
}
```

Comment: Is onDraw(canvas) the function that renders the view?

Answer (score 1):

You can put a logger just before redirecting it on view in your controller and print time-stamp and also put another logger in you view at end and again print time-stamp and them you can compare both timestamps and difference would be rendering time.